# Change an ellipse/circle's size from the center after it has been drawn

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector

I've drawn several vector circles (all on different shape layers) in Photoshop and now would like to change their size to make them a bit smaller. Is there a way to do this and have them shrink/grow from the center?

If I select the layer then select the ellipse shape tool I can adjust the size from the tool options but that doesn't make the shape grow/shrink from the center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the fields in the Control Bar to change the size, ensure the 9-point origin is set to the center dot:

[image]

If using Free Transform, hold down <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and drag a corner. Option/Alt makes the transformation from the center, and Shift ensures it stays proportional to the original.

Comment: Wow - now I feel dumb - no idea why I didn't think of free transform before.

Answer (score 3):

1. Bring up the `Free Transform` controls, by hitting <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
2. Hold down <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>OPTION</kbd> while you resize.

This will maintain the object's proportions and allow you to resize from its center.